# Jenkins, Maven, Slaves and artifacts

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins, synchronization, artifact

I have a Master Jenkins running on a Windows machine. I'm trying to add a Linux slave and so far seems fine. For some reason if a new project is ran on the Linux Machine that triggers another project due to dependencies, the build fail because is unable to see the artifacts from the first project.

If I run everything on the master (i.e. disabling the slave) it works fine. I suspect is some kind of artifact sharing that needs to take place, but I haven't been able to find examples or figure out how to do this synchronization.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you archiving the build artifact, as a post build action?

Comment: Yes, also fingerprints.

Comment: Are you using "Copy Artifacts" plugin to bring the artifacts from one build to another?

Comment: I'm not since they are Maven artifacts.